# Creating ArrayList of a Class defined in a variable

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

Suppose I have something like this

```
Class klazz = Integer.class;
```

And I'm interested in doing something like this

```
List<(klazz Class)> something = new ArrayList<>();

something.add(new Integer(..))
something.add(new Integer(..))
.. etc
```

I probably need to use reflection, yet however, I'm unsure about how to apply it.

Is it possible to do without reflection? If it's not, how would you find it suitable to implement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Type parameters help you at compile time only.  At run time, they disappear.  So setting the type parameter at run time, based on different values of `klazz` doesn't really fit how generics work.  I'd suggest just using a `List<Object>` and having some logic to ensure that only objects of type `klazz` go into it.

Comment: please, if possible add it as a response. I'll check it out later and assign at as response if there's nothing useful yet

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `klazz` is `String.class`?

Comment: I expect something to be List<String>

Comment: `List<Class>` supposed to add only `Class` elements, `new Integer(..)` will not fit into this.

Comment: It's not a List<Class>, it's a List<klazz.getType()> or sth like that... klazz's class

Comment: What I mean is, how do you know `klazz` is `Integer.class` in this example?

Comment: It's just an example, it could be either Integer.class, or String.class or anything. 

And I'd like to create a List<klazz value> ex: if klazz is Person.class, then list would be of type List<Person>. Although generics are only useful during compilation time. If this is not a posibility then I'll have to proceed without generics

Comment: Actually, if I post a response, it will be very similar to what J-Alex wrote, so I shan't bother.

Comment: You're missing my point. What would be the purpose of restricting it to a runtime type? How would you know what types you can add at compile time?

Comment: Why do you come up with situation where you have to initialize your `List` from a random type? Could you post some relevant code and may be we will have some other good way around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot completely undertand the requirement, but this may help:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContainerWrapper<Integer> containerWrapper = new ContainerWrapper<>(Integer.class);
        containerWrapper.add(1);
        System.out.println(containerWrapper.containerType());
        System.out.println(containerWrapper.isInteger());
    }
}

class ContainerWrapper<T> {
    // Store type information here
    private Class<T> clazz;
    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public ContainerWrapper(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void add(T element) {
        list.add(element);
    }

    public Class<T> containerType() {
        return clazz;
    }

    public boolean isInteger() {
        return clazz.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class);
    }
}
```

You can check `T` type using `clazz.isAssignableFrom(*.class)`

Output:

```
class java.lang.Integer
true
```

Comment: You have Integer hardcoded here: `ContainerWrapper<Integer>`, is there any way this could be dynamically set by a Class variable? If not then I'd have to stick to use no generics at all, but it's not considered good practice.

Comment: Only like `ContainerWrapper<Object>`, as was proposed in the first comment.

Comment: It's nothing different than `List<T>`.